# Extracting column from dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary `d` where keys are associated with a pandas dataframe. So, I can execute `print(d[0]['col1']` and I'm able to return `col1` for key `0`.

If I print `d` , I have something like this for key `0`-

```
{0:                               col1       type         Weather  \
0                                    id    varchar                  
1                                    id    varchar                  
2                                    id    varchar                  
3                                    id    varchar                  
4                                    id    varchar                  
..                               ...        ...            ...
```

The expected outcome becomes

```
{0:                     col1
0                       id
1                       id
2                       id
3                       id
4                       id
..                               ...
```

But how can I apply this to all keys? So my dictionary only includes `col1`. I've been stuck on this for awhile, any guidance appreciated.

Comment: So you want to print all dataframes in each key in the dictionary with only `col1` displayed. Is that correct?

Comment: I'd like the dictionary to only display ```col1``` as a value

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please [edit] to show a [mcve] with sample input, expected output, and code for what you've tried so far

Comment: I've tried to edit for more clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {0:pd.DataFrame({'col0':[0,1,2], 'col1':[0,0,0]}),
    1:pd.DataFrame({'col0':[1,2,3], 'col1':[1,1,1]})}

def get_cols(d,cols):
    for key, value in d.items():
        d[key] = value[cols]
    return d
```

this will get you a series for the column chosen

```
print(get_cols(d,'col0'))
```

this will get you a df for the column chosen

```
print(get_cols(d,['col0']))
```

this will get you a df for the columns chosen

```
print(get_cols(d,['col0','col1']))
```

**note:** this strategy modifies `d`, as it is passed by reference. you could also return `None` and just use d, or deep copy `d` before modifying it in the function.

Comment: after extracting ```col1``` how might I convert this dataframe column to a ```list```?

Comment: a Series is somewhat equivalent to a list (data frames are like lists of series, conceptually), so if you get the series `col1` with `get_cols(d,'col1')` you should be able to cast that as a list with `list(get_cols(d,'col1'))`. that, or a series might have a `to_list()` function or something. That said, I would recommend working with pandas datatypes directly, they're way more powerful.

Comment: For future readers, you may want to look into multindexing. Looking at this question again, storing dictionaries of pandas data frames doesn't seem particularly coacher.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using dictionary comprehension?

```
import pandas as pd

df0 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': [3,4,5], 'col3': [5,6,7]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [7,8,9], 'col2': [10,11,12], 'col3': [13,14,15]})

d = {}
d[0] = df0
d[1] = df1


print({x:d[x]['col1'] for x in d})
```

If you want the output without index you can replace the last line with either

```
print({x:d[x]['col1'].values for x in d})
```

or

```
print({x:d[x]['col1'].tolist() for x in d})
```